# Sharing large files between airflow operators

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Let's assume an airflow DAG consists of the following two operators:

- Op1 (`GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator`): Downloads the file XYZ from GCS
- Op2 (`PythonOperator`): Needs the file XYZ to do something with it

The DAG will be executed by GCP's Composer. I know it is possible to combine the two operators, and implement them as one `PythonOperator`, but I want to do it more modular, and use builtin operators as much as possible.

**Candidate Solutions:**

- Use a temporary file: temporary files cannot be used. If XYZ is stored as /tmp/XYZ, Op2 may or may not find it, since the two Operators might be run by different workers.
- xcom: xcom cannot also be used here since the file is rather large.
- Use GCS as a shared storage: It does not work in this particular example. We are back to where we are, since one operator still needs to do the downloading and availing the file for the second operator.

So, what is a good solution here? In general, is there a way to hand off a file (or a string) from one operator to another?

Comment: You say that OP2 can't read directly from GCS but didn't explain why. In general this is the solution for such scenario. Upload the file into a shared disk. Is GCS banned completely from OP2 or is it a specific bucket / folder? Can you create a bucket that will be used as a shared disk so your OP1 will be GcsToGcs? If not - then sorry either combine Op1 and Op2 into one operator or Upgrade to Airflow 2 and define a XCom backend that fits to the size of data you want to share between operators.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned, there is no issue to have Op2 directly reading from GCS (I actually did that using the client library). My goal is to modularize the code and use the builtin Operators such as GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator when possible. I am using airflow-1.10.12 which is what Composer currently offers. I doubt I can upgrade that on my own. So I guess this path is a deadend, which makes me wonder if GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator can be used anywhere at all.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant for your use case. What you can do is create a custom operator of your own combining OP1 and OP2 into a new OP that you can utilize for other dags as well. This is a very common practice.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket). A gcsfuse filesystem exists on the composer pods. In your composer code, you can locally access it by `/home/airflow/gcs`.

So, in the example above, Op1 needs to copy XYZ from the other bucket to the composer bucket. This can be done using `GCSToGCSOperator`:

```py
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_gcs import GCSToGCSOperator

MY_BUCKET='Original Bucket containing XYZ'
PATH_TO_XYZ='path/to/XYZ'
COMPOSER_BUCKET = os.environ.get('GCS_BUCKET')
XYZ_GCS_PATH = 'data/my_dir/XYZ'
XYZ_LOCAL_PATH = f'/home/airflow/gcs/{XYZ_GCS_PATH}'

def my_function(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as f:
     content = f.read()
     print(content)


with models.DAG(...) as dag:
  Op1 = GCSToGCSOperator(
      task_id='download_data',
      source_bucket=MY_BUCKET,
      source_object=PATH_TO_XYZ,
      destination_bucket=COMPOSER_BUCKET,
      destination_object=XYZ_GCS_PATH,
  )

  Op1 = PythonOperator(
      task_id='read_file',
      python_callable=my_function,
      op_kwargs={'filepath': XYZ_LOCAL_PATH}
  )

  Op1 >> Op2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, intermediary files. using xcom to pass the path to the file

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution a bit more? What is an intermediary file? Is it an airflow component?

Comment: You write the data to a file '/path/to'file ', if you are using a python operator you can return this path to use further on as xcoms, ie. kwargs['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='task_id')
which will return the filepath you sent via xcom. you can also use this inside functions or jinja templating